# Visual Intuition: Gaussians closed under addition

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, intuition, visualization

I'm trying to develop some intuition for the fact that the family of Gaussian distributions is closed under addition.

I.e. if $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$, then $Y = \sum_iX_i$ is also normal with $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\sum_i \mu_i, \sum_i \sigma_i^2)$.

If I [graph the PDF](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1p6scoizgq) of $Y$ for some arbitrary $X_1$ and $X_2$, I just cannot believe that the resulting distribution is Normal - it clearly seems like this distribution could be bi-modal;

[image: Example graph of the PDF of Y = X_1 + X_2]

Wikipedia has several [analytic proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) for this problem, but they are a bit dense and I was hoping to develop some visual intuition for this property. Am I misunderstanding something regarding the graph of the PDF of $Y$?

Comment: Density of X+Y is NOT $f_X(x)+f_Y(y)$, which is what you graphed.

Comment: @aaron Intuitively, you know that the average of $X+Y$ should be around the sum of the averages of $X$ and $Y$ so it doesn't make sense for it to be bimodal. Also intuitively, if $\int_\mathbb{R}f_X=1$ and $\int_\mathbb{R}f_Y=1$ then adding those two PDFs would give you $\int_\mathbb{R}f_X+f_Y=2$, which can't be right.

Comment: https://math.la.asu.edu/~jtaylor/teaching/Fall2010/STP421/lectures/lecture20.pdf

Comment: @Jam Post owners will be notified in case of comments, and there's no need to tag them.